# Isotope gallery not always working properly

Tags: html, css, fancybox, gallery, jquery-isotope

I am working on a isotope gallery, and sometimes its not working properly, i needed to refresh the page a few times because i made some changes to the front end, and i saw that the portfolio works different on each refresh.

EDIT: only does this on Chrome.

this is how it should work:

[image: Working isotope gallery]

but sometimes it does things like this:

[image: after refreshing the page]

Here's [the link](http://www.plus-bus.nl/index.php) to the website, and here is my isotope gallery code:

i left out a few items, since i found out it doesnt matter how much items i put in the gallery.

```
<!-- section works -->
    <section id="section-works" class="section appear clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="filter" class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="current btn-theme btn-small" data-filter="*">Alles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"  class="btn-theme btn-small" data-filter=".photo" >Foto's</a>    </li>
                        <li><a href="#"  class="btn-theme btn-small" data-filter=".video">Video's</a>    </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="portfolio-items isotopeWrapper clearfix" id="3">

                            <article class="col-md-4 isotopeItem photo">
                                <div class="portfolio-item">
                                    <img src="img/portfolio/img1.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <div class="portfolio-desc align-center">
                                        <div class="folio-info">
                                            <h5><a href="#">Portfolio name</a></h5>
                                            <a href="img/portfolio/img1.jpg" class="fancybox"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-2x"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>

                            <article class="col-md-4 isotopeItem video">
                                <div class="portfolio-item">
                                    <img src="img/portfolio/img6.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <div class="portfolio-desc align-center">
                                        <div class="folio-info">
                                            <h5><a href="#">Portfolio name</a></h5>
                                            <a class="fancybox" href="js/jwPlayer5/player.swf?    file=http://localhost/plusbus/img/portfolio/videos/files/vid1.mp4"     type="video/mp4" title="local video mp4"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-2x"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You need to post your isotope code, not just your html. I don't see any images  on your site as posted here. How about a link at least to that. A jsfiddle is best.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is a bit of a guess. You are using isotope v1.56, not v2, you need to use [Isoptope v1 imagesloaded info](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/images.html).

This is how you use it:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
 $container.isotope({
// options...
 });
 });
```

For isotope v2, you would need to load imagesloaded.js separately since it is not included as it is in v1.5